# Redefinition of \maketitle is ignored

Tags: macros, titles, definition, renewcommand

I would like to change some elements of my title page, but without completely creating my own titlepage environment (as e.g. demonstrated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/182643)), because I am using commands like `\extratitle` and `\uppertitleback` and I'd rather not recreate them all.

I am using a KOMA-class and luckily, [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494204/182643) not only explains how to redefine `\maketitle` in such a case, but also includes the original definition of it, so it is easy for me to adapt.

But for some reason, my new definition is ignored when `\maketitle` is called, and the default one is used instead. It gets even stranger however, because when I call `\makeatletter\meaning\@maketitle\makeatother` (which should show me the current definition of `maketitle` according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216121/182643)), it produces the *new* definition, both before and after I call `\maketitle`. What's going on here?

Also, when I create an entirely new command that way, e.g. `\makecustomtitle`, the compiler says it doesn't know it: `Undefined control sequence.`

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@maketitle}{%
% \newcommand*{\@makecustomtitle}{%
%   \global\@topnum=\z@
%   \setparsizes{\z@}{\z@}{\z@\@plus 1fil}\par@updaterelative
%   \ifx\@titlehead\@empty \else
%     \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
%       \usekomafont{titlehead}{\@titlehead\par}%
%     \end{minipage}\par
%   \fi
%   \null
%   \vskip 2em%
% %  \begin{center}%
%     \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
%       {\usekomafont{subject}{\@subject \par}}%
%       \vskip 1.5em
%     \fi
%     {\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
%     \vskip .5em
%     {\usekomafont{title}{\huge \@title \par}}%
%     \vskip 1em
%     {%
%       \usekomafont{author}{%
%         \lineskip .5em%
%         \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
%           \@author
%         \end{tabular}\par
%       }%
%     }%
%     \vskip 1em%
%     {\usekomafont{date}{\@date \par}}%
%     \vskip \z@ \@plus 1em
%     {\usekomafont{publishers}{\@publishers \par}}%
%     \ifx\@dedication\@empty \else
%       \vskip 2em
%       {\usekomafont{dedication}{\@dedication \par}}%
%     \fi
% %  \end{center}%
%   \par
%   \vskip 2em
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subtitle{This is a subtitle}
\title{This is a title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter\meaning\@maketitle\makeatother
\maketitle
\makeatletter\meaning\@maketitle\makeatother

% \makecustomtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: `scrbook` is not the same as `scrartcl` though. Maybe you'll have to resort to reading the source code of `\maketitle` in this document class to see what the definition is and adapt

Comment: You are not redefining `\maketitle` but `\@maketitle`, which is AFAIK only used for on page title heads (option `titlepage=false`), but not for title pages (option `titlepage=true`, which is default with `scrbook`).

Comment: BTW: Package `uni-titlepage` is AFAIK more or less compatible with KOMA-Script classes. So you could load the KOMA-Script style of that package and change only the first title page by redefining `\makemaintitle`.

Comment: @user202729 that's true. I'll have a look.

Comment: @cabohah ah thank you. I thought the `@` had to do with the `\makeatletter` commands. I didn't realize they are actually different commands. The `uni-titlepage` may be a good option. Apparently it's from the `KOMA` author.

Comment: `\makeatletter ` is "make @ letter" so after that  `\@maketitle` is a  command name just like `\xmaketitle` as @ is just a letter